# Is it possible to retrieve the first ever post using social media APIs?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

For any developers out there experienced using various social media APIs (Facebook, Instagram, Twitter), I was wondering if it is possible to retrieve the first original post a user posted to the social media account?

I am looking to develop a site where the user could authenticate the various platforms (mentioned above) and then their first ever original posts for each of the various platforms would be retrieved and then shown to them.

Is that even possible using each platform’s APIs?

Comment: Each API works differently. It's hard to make an assumption for every social media. You could simply check what each API has to offer. If you can filter all posts by date it should do the trick. But honestly I don't think it is possible. Otherwise the internet would be flooded with pages like your idea. Also there are still private and deleted posts, which could be older. The oldest YouTube video changed several times over the years.

Comment: @SickerDude43 - Thanks for the insight. I somewhat expected that to be the case since I was thinking the same thing. There would probably already be a lot of sites out there that would do it.